# C program to shift arrays of number by N places to the right buy not working properly

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, while-loop, user-input

This is a C program that i wrote to achieve the following purpose.

> User needs to provide an integer array A of size N and an integer K ,
> where the program needs to rotate the array in the right direction by
> K steps and then print the resultant array.
>
> Input Format:
>
> The first line will consists of one integer T denoting the number of
> test cases. For each test case: The first line consists of two
> integers N and K, N being the number of elements in the array and K
> denotes the number of steps of rotation. The next line consists of N
> space separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.
>
> Output Format:
>
> Print the array after rotation in the single line for each test case.

[These are sample input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/derwD.jpg)
This is the code that i wrote to achieve the purpose,

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  main()
{   int i,n,a[100],temp,shiftlimit,cyclelimit;
    int shiftcount = 0;
    int cyclcount = 0;
    scanf("%d",&cyclelimit);
    while(cyclcount != cyclelimit){

        scanf("%d",&n);
        scanf("%d",&shiftlimit);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }while(shiftcount != shiftlimit){
            temp=a[n-1];
            for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
            {
                a[i]=a[i-1];
            }
            a[0]=temp;
            shiftcount += 1;}
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");cyclcount +=1;}
}
```

---

And there are some complexity parameter as follows:
[Complexity parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCWZ.jpg)
This code works fine when  `T= cyclelimit` (line 7) is 1 but as soon as user enters 2 or more the code starts to malfunction.
I have use while loop to achieve the purpose but it is not working after 1 loop.

---

My output:
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmeNv.jpg)
Required Ouput:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p4yW.jpg)

Comment: Remove the line numbers (or comment them out to make copying and compiling the code possible) and indent your code properly.

Comment: And put the actual and expected outputs directly into the question, as text.

Comment: [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Comment: quick debugging tip .. hardcode at least your array for now. That will save a lot of time from entering numbers for the array each test iteration. In fact I would hardcode everything until I got the rotation algorithm working.

Comment: @phuclv heh well, as you can see I'm a huge proponent of line numbers, one of SO's worst and baffling omissions IMO. But certainly not implemented this way since you can't copy and paste the code.

Comment: You need to reset `shiftcount` back to 0 for each cycle.

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger. If you have no debugger (but you really should...) you can add debugging traces. If you have dumped the value of `shiftcount` you would have seen that it is not reset to 0 on a second test case. Just add `shiftcount = 0;` at the beginning of the loop. (I am too lazy to format that into a correct answer, feel free to use my comment to build one...)

Comment: Instead of reading and then shifting, consider reading each element directly into its final position.  It's simpler to implement (really!), and there's less that can go wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a neat solution but it feels like cheating! Also, if the goal is merely to print the right answer, that could also be done by reading the elements in order and fiddling with the loop to print them.

Comment: Well, @Ian, for my next trick I read the input into array elements corresponding to their input order, create an auxiliary array of size N, and copy elements from the input into the target positions of the auxiliary.  I then either output the auxiliary, or if that's still not good enough then I `memcpy()` it back over the original.  But really, if there are requirements on the implementation details then they should be presented in the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was going off "where the program needs to rotate the array in the right direction by K steps and then print the resultant array". If marks are given for coding, I think doing anything other than rotating the array contents would lose marks! (Of course OP's code would probably lose marks anyway for not handling negative shift amounts, and for doing K rotations of step size 1 instead of 1 rotation of step size K.)

Answer (score 0):

1., Use functions - do not program in main.
2. Use standard functions.

```
int *allocateArr(size_t N)
{

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * N);
    return arr;
}

int *rotateLeft(int *arr, size_t N, size_t K)
{
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * K);  /* check for errors*/

    for(size_t i = 0; i < K; i ++) temp[i] = arr[i];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N - K; i ++) arr[i] = arr[K + i];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < K; i ++) arr[i + (N - K)] = temp[i];
    free(temp);
    return arr;
}

int *rotateRight(int *arr, size_t N, size_t K)
{
    return rotateLeft(arr, N, N - K);
}


#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int *arr = allocateArr(SIZE);  /* check for errors*/
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) arr[i - 1] = i;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    rotateRight(arr, SIZE, 4);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) arr[i - 1] = i;
    rotateLeft(arr, SIZE, 4);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(arr);
}
```

```
int *allocateArr(size_t N)
{

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * N);
    return arr;
}

int *rotateLeft(int *arr, size_t N, size_t K)
{
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * K);  /* check for errors*/

    memcpy(temp, arr, sizeof(*arr) * K);
    memmove(arr, arr + K, sizeof(*arr) * (N - K));
    memcpy(arr + (N - K), temp, sizeof(*arr) * K);
    free(temp);
    return arr;
}

int *rotateRight(int *arr, size_t N, size_t K)
{
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * K);  /* check for errors*/

    memcpy(temp, arr + (N - K), sizeof(*arr) * K);
    memmove(arr + K, arr, sizeof(*arr) * (N - K));
    memcpy(arr, temp, sizeof(*arr) * K);
    free(temp);
    return arr;
}


#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int *arr = allocateArr(SIZE);  /* check for errors*/
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) arr[i - 1] = i;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    rotateRight(arr, SIZE, 4);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) arr[i - 1] = i;
    rotateLeft(arr, SIZE, 4);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(arr);
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 
5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the active response and specially    Ian , 0___________ , Serge Ballesta for the help.